# Get record achieving the quota using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Having the record below with Achieving Quota is 30:

```
ContractNos   Sale    SaleDate    Agent
    1         10      01/01/16     A
    2         20      01/10/16     A
    3         20      01/10/16     A
    4         10      01/11/16     A
    5         40      01/20/16     B
    6         20      01/21/16     C
    7         30      01/22/16     C
    8         10      01/23/16     C
```

How to get the record per agent where their sale is achieved the certain quota which is 30 order by SaleDate Ascending. Ideal Results must be like this:

```
ContractNos   Sale    SaleDate    Agent
    1         10      01/01/16     A  -> ADD THIS
    2         20      01/10/16     A  -> RECORD = 30 achieved the quota
    3         20      01/10/16     A     
    4         10      01/11/16     A
    5         40      01/20/16     B  -> Quota is achieved which is 30
    6         20      01/21/16     C  -> ADD THIS
    7         30      01/22/16     C  -> RECORD = 50 achieved the quota 
    8         10      01/23/16     C
```

Final Results

```
ContractNos   Sale    SaleDate    Agent
    1         10      01/01/16     A
    2         20      01/10/16     A
    5         40      01/20/16     B
    6         20      01/21/16     C
    7         30      01/22/16     C
```

Comment: which version of sql server you are using

Comment: What about records 3 and 4? Summing the sales in them also reaches 30. Why are they not included in the results?

Comment: As long the agent the reached the quota the rest will not included I need only the top sale which is order by Sale of Date ascending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `Sql Server 2008` does not support `Sum() Over(order by)` window function to calculate running total.

Use `Correlated sub-query method` to calculate running total

Try this

```
SELECT ContractNos,
       Sale,
       SaleDate,
       Agent
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT Sum([Sale])
                FROM   yourtable  b
                WHERE  a.[Agent] = b.[Agent]
                       AND a.[ContractNos] >= b.[ContractNos]) run_sum,*
        FROM   yourtable a) c
WHERE  run_sum - sale < 30
```

or use `Cross Apply`

```
SELECT ContractNos,
       Sale,
       SaleDate,
       Agent
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   yourtable a
               CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([Sale])
                            FROM   yourtable b
                            WHERE  a.[Agent] = b.[Agent]
                                   AND a.[ContractNos] >= b.[ContractNos]) c(run_sum)) a
WHERE  run_sum - sale < 30
```

For `Sql Server 2012+` use this

```
SELECT ContractNos,
           Sale,
           SaleDate,
           Agent
FROM   (SELECT Sum([Sale])OVER(partition BY [Agent] ORDER BY [ContractNos]) run_sum,*
        FROM   yourtable) a
WHERE  run_sum - sale < 30
```

Comment: @Ruhaan - Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is calculate running total with a join:

```
select s1.ContractNos, s1.Sale, s1.SaleDate, s1.Agent
  from sales s1
       left join sales s2
       on s1.ContractNos >= s2.ContractNos and s1.Agent = s2.Agent
 group by s1.ContractNos, s1.Sale, s1.SaleDate, s1.Agent
 having sum(s2.sale) - s1.sale < 30 
 order by s1.ContractNos
```